# Redis not picking up Broadcast events in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-5

I have the following event:

```
<?php

namespace SixtyFiveContrib\Events;

use Auth;

use SixtyFiveContrib\Events\Event;
use SixtyFiveContrib\Models\Notification;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

/**
 * NotificationEvent 
 *
 */
class NotificationEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $notification;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Notification $notification)
    {
        $this->notification = $notification;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['feed', 'updates'];
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['notification' => $this->notification];
    }
}
```

I'm using the Redis driver in broadcasting.php

```
 'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],
```

Then I have the node app from the official docs, which runs fine and connects to the client:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server is running!');
});

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Ayup.');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //
});

redis.psubscribe('*', function(err, count) {
    console.log(err);
});

redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);

    console.log(subscribed);
    console.log(channel);
    console.log(message);

    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
```

The node app isn't receiving anything from Redis? If I manually go into redis-cli and run ``` PUBLISH feed '{event: "SixtyFiveContrib\Events\NotificationEvent"}' then the node app does receive that message.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Are you by any chance using the redis session and cache drivers as well?

Comment: @DavidBarker I am indeed! Will that cause some form of conflict?

Comment: It did a while ago when I played around with it for the first time before 5.1 was released. I had to set the cache driver to anything other than redis to get it working.

Comment: Are you sure, you have configured the driver in the .env file. The broadcasting.php has that line 'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),

Answer (score 5):

Had this problem myself just now.

Apparently, **broadcasted events** use the `QUEUE_DRIVER`:

[See "Queue Prerequisites"](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#broadcasting-events):

> Before broadcasting events, you will also need to configure and run a queue listener. All event broadcasting is done via queued jobs so that the response time of your application is not seriously affected.

So, to catch the events immediately, you could set `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`.
But this is of course not advised, since all your other jobs would run in sync as well.
So it's better to set up a proper queue handler first.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this.  I switched the `QUEUE_DRIVER` from sync and did not have the listener running on my local machine, so events were never broadcast.  I wish I could upvote this 1000 time more.

Answer (score 0):

Unknown reason but it works with me

```
redis.psubscribe("*") => redis.subscribe("feed")
```