# Laravel events are not showing up in node using redis

Tags: php, node.js, apache, redis, laravel-5

I followed the guide here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51 and installed redis and node on my OSX El Capitan and everything seemed to work nicely at first but nothing happens in node when I fire my events in laravel.

It simply starts and says 'Listening on Port 3000' and never says anything more when I run events in Laravel. I see nothing in the laravel logs.

my socket.js file, located in the laravel root directory, looks like this

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('default', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

I then have a route called fire that looks like this

```
Route::get('fire', function () {
    // this fires the event
    Event::fire(new App\Events\TestEvent());
    return "event fired";
});
```

My TestEvent looks like this

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestEvent extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'power'=> '10'
        );
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['default'];
    }
}
```

Redis seems to be running fine

```
redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I do not seem to have any problems connecting to node either and all my ports are open, im not running a firewall. I added the following to my .env file.

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
```

**How can I debug this error or what are some likely reasons that this is happening?**

Comment: I usually do a lot of research before posting but just found that it may be an issue with trying to use redis for my queue and broadcasting? This is the topic I found https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/any-use-redis-as-queue-and-broadcast-driver-same-time?page=1

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I believe my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028455/redis-not-picking-up-broadcast-events-in-laravel-5-1 I simply searched for the wrong problem